# (1 and 3) OR (2 AND 4) AND (5 OR 6) Identify releation

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, formatting

I have string : - `(1 and 3) OR (2 AND 4) AND (5 OR 6)`

I want to know the relation between each number with another in C# 4.0 on above string

Like :

```
relation between 1 , 3 is - AND 
relation between 1 , 2 is - OR
relation between 1 , 4 is - OR 
relation between 1 , 5 is - AND
relation between 1 , 6 is - AND
```

same as above I need identify the relation for each element.

Do some needful , If any has tried it

Comment: You mean all you have is a string and you want to know if the part inside the parathesis is `AND` or `OR` and the same for outside them? Regex seems to be the right tool then. What have you tried?

Comment: How is the 'relation' between 1, 2 OR ??? That is no relation. The 'relation' between (1 and 3), (2 and 4) is OR

Comment: Are the numbers fixed (1 to 6 only)? The format and pattern of the input string is fixed (space between numbers)?

Comment: Agreed with @Erno I don't fully understand the logic here.